# Update Column to a Value

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I'm trying to update a column to a value in Mapinfo/Mapbasic using

```
Add Column "MMT_PARCEL_MP" (Limited_StratumTF )From Limited_Stratum Set To "T" Where intersects
```

and just getting an 'Unable to update table' error message
The table is editable and I can update it manually with no problems.
The intersect statement works with no problems in a query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes packing the tables used helps. This is especially a problem when you are updating one table with values from another table.

You can also try to do it via the interface with the MapBasic window open. Afterwards check if your syntax is similar to the syntax shown in the MapBasic window.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have non-objects in a table.

```
select * from Limited_Stratum where not Obj into selection
```